# Why character from character array, received from recursive function is not shown?

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to learn recursion in Java. I am trying to print English alphabets from A to Z. But when I run the code, something undesirable is printed. What happened to my A-Z characters?

The code is given below:

```
public class Recursion_Maharaj {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Recursion...");
        char[] alphabet = alphabets('A');
        for (char c :alphabet) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }

    static char[] alphabets(char S){
        int start = (int) S; // ASCII = 65
        int end = 'Z';// ASCII = 90
        char character;
        char[] ret = new char[26];
        if (start <= end){
            start++;
            character = (char) start;
            ret = alphabets(character);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

The output is *some undesirable character.*

What mistake I am making?

Comment: You never actually write anything into `ret` - you just repeatedly create new arrays filled with default values

Comment: At some point you need to have `ret[index] = character`, where the `index` and `character` change each recursive call, and you need to use the same `char[]` _instance_ throughout the recursion. Currently you don't do the former and you're creating a _new array_ every recursive call.

Comment: maybe returning a string and concatenating with the character would be easier... `return S + alphabets(character);` || please stick to the java naming convention (e.g. variable and parameters start with lowercase letter)

Comment: BTW you do not need that lot of variables - it is valid to do `if (S < 'Z')` or even `S += 1` (or `alphabets((char)(S+1))` - cast needed since integer (binary) operations result in `int` if no `long` is involved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze your code. Let's start with the **last** invocation of method `alphabets`. The value of the method parameter, i.e. `S`, will be *[* (which is the character after *Z* in the ASCII table), hence the `if` condition will be false, hence the method will return an array of 26 elements where each element is the null character, i.e. a character whose ASCII code is zero – because in this line of code:

```java
char[] ret = new char[26];
```

Java will implicitly initialize each array element to zero.

So the last invocation returns an array of null characters to the second last invocation, which is this line of code:

```java
ret = alphabets(character);
```

And therefore the second last invocation also returns an array of null characters – and so on until you return to the first invocation which returns the array of null characters in this line of your code:

```java
char[] alphabet = alphabets('A');
```

So when you print the contents of `alphabet`, it prints what appears to be 26 empty lines. Actually it is printing 26 lines where each line displays a single, null character. If you change the `for` loop to the following, it will print 26 zeroes.

```java
for (char c :alphabet) {
    System.out.println((int) c);
}
```

You need to make the array one of the parameters of method `alphabets` and in the body of method `alphabets` you assign a value to an element of that array. Actually, I suggest using a `List` rather than an array because a `List`, unlike an array, does not have a fixed size and you cannot know, before-hand, how many letters will be added to the `List`. If your initial invocation is changed to:

```java
char[] alphabet = alphabets('Y');
```

then how many letters should be returned? Not 26, right?

Here is my rewrite of your code:
(Note that `char` is a primitive and you cannot have a `List` of primitives.)

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Recursion_Maharaj {
    private static void getLetters(List<Character> letters, char letter) {
        if (letter <= 'Z') {
            letters.add(letter);
            getLetters(letters, (char) (letter + 1));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Recursion...");
        List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
        getLetters(list, 'A');
        for (Character c : list) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code prints the following:

```
Recursion...
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z
```

And if I change the initial invocation to:

```java
getLetters(list, 'Y');
```

then the output is:

```
Recursion...
Y
Z
```